# my copy array function didn't work. i didn't understand why

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, copy, function-definition

This code has to copy one array to another via void copy function. But I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copy(int func_array_1[], int func_array_2[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        func_array_1[i] = func_array_2[i];
}

int main() {

    int size = 0;
    int array[10] = { 0 };
    int copy_array[10] = { 0 };
    printf("Input the number of elements to be stored in the array :");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);

    copy(array, copy_array, size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d", copy_array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

---

It gives first defined array members which are all zero.

Comment: You have a typo func_array_1[i] = func_array_2[i];    You need to write func_array_2[i] = func_array_1[i];

Comment: What is the input you give the program? What is the output you get from the program? What is the output you *expect* from the program? Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to [edit] your questions.

Comment: I also suggest this is a good time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. Also please read [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Your `copy` function copies from the second array to the first array.  But you're calling it with the two arrays reversed.  Decide what argument order you want, then use it consistently.  Also, I think you gave up too soon in your debugging attempts.  You should have been able to find this on your own.

Comment: Also, since you're programming in C you should probably use [*variable-length arrays*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) rather than hardcode the size using the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) `10`. It will make it *very* easy to enter a too large value for `size`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
>     func_array_1[i] = func_array_2[i];
> ```

You're copying from the zero-initialized array to the one you actually want to copy to.
So just change the loop body to:

```
func_array_2[i] = func_array_1[i];
```

Using **const** and / or more purposeful naming could've prevented your error.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the function

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    func_array_1[i] = func_array_2[i];      
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As the function is called like

```
copy(array, copy_array, size);
```

you have to write

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    func_array_2[i] = func_array_1[i];      
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The reason of the typo is a bad function declaration. The function should be declared at least like

```
void copy( const int func_array_1[], int func_array_2[], int size);
```

That is the array that is not being changed within the function should be declared with the qualifier `const`.

Instead of the for loop you could use the standard function `memcpy` declared in the header `<string.h>` as for example

```
memcpy( func_array_2, func_array_1, size * sizeof( int ) );
```

Pay attention to that you need to check that the entered value of the variable `size` is not greater than `10`.